# Creating subdomain on Amazon EC2 does not works

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, subdomain, nameservers, amazon-route53

I want to create a subdomain from a real, living site which I will call example.com. The subdomain has to be named subdomain.example.com. Everything is running on a Amazon EC2 instance.

I just can't access the subdomain.example.com, when trying to access this URL, the browser shows the usual "Server not found" message.

I followed the next steps (includes steps from other StackOverflow answers):

1.-Acquired the domain example.com at GoDaddy.

2.-Linked correctly the example.com website to the real server, so the main site works fine.

3.-Went to the Amazon EC2 Console and created a EIP (Elastic IP)

4.-Went to Route53 and added a new Hosted Zone just like this article says (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html)
So that at I can see the subdomain.example.com Hosted Zone, and inside it there is a A Record that points to my Elastic IP.

5.-Went to the server and checked that the line "NameVirtualHost *:80" is there.

6.-Created a Virtual Host directive like the next one:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.example.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@subdomain.example.com

  DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/frameworks/codeigniter/htdocs

  <Directory /opt/bitnami/frameworks/codeigniter/htdocs>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/subdomain.example.com.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/subdomain.example.com.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

7.- Restarted the apache server

However, as stated at the start of the post, I can't ping or access the website.
**What step could I be missing?**

Are there chances that the change hasn't been propagraget yet? One day after the subdomain creation I'm still unable to access the website.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, thanks to @Sergey and @datasage, the updated step list:

4.1- Go to your GoDaddy account (or your alternate provider) and add the 4 addresses obtained from Route 53 Hosted Zones, these addresses are under the label "Delegation Set".
4.2- Wait for about an hour until the changes are done (in my case it worked instantly for some reason)

Here is an useful article about these steps: http://blog.sefindustries.com/redirect-a-subdomain-to-route-53-from-godaddy/

Answer (score 1):

**Check subdomain.example.com, if record exists in DNS or propagated well:**

1. Ask you default "home" DNS server

> dig -t A subdomain.example.com

1. Ask google dns

> dig -t A subdomain.example.com @8.8.8.8

1. Ask your authorized DNS server

> dig -t A subdomain.example.com @your.ns.server

**In case of windows use nslookup**

or

**Use internet service (for example [digweb](http://www.digwebinterface.com/))**

Comment: From digweb, after querying the subdomain.example.com (with the right name of course) I got exactly:


example.com.  1786 IN SOA ns03.domaincontrol.com. dns.jomax.net. 2014011900 28800 7200 604800 600

I don't know exactly what it means. Is it finding the server?

Comment: Is your domain configured to use route 53 as its DNS servers? domaincontrol.com = godaddy

Comment: Thanks @datasage and @Sergey! The information led me to this article: http://blog.sefindustries.com/redirect-a-subdomain-to-route-53-from-godaddy/ which addresses the missing step of adding the NS NameServers obtained from step 4.